# Traffic Incident API - How do the START_TIME, END_TIME and ENTRY_TIME parameters work?

Tags: here-api

How exactly do the START_TIME, END_TIME and ENTRY_TIME parameters work and how are they affected when an incident is updated?

I would assume that START_TIME is the time the incident is reported (or due to start in the case of roadworks), END_TIME is the when the incident is expected to be over and ENTRY_TIME when the incident was registered with HERE? Is this correct? I have not been able to find any documentation for this.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Sometime, there wont be clear information about end time,  so endTime will be updated as long as event is active.

Comment: To clarify, START_TIME is start time of an event, not reported time.

Answer (score 0):

An array of  elements that contain the incident location, time, duration, severity, description and other details. The keys are the logical named keys. You can refer more details at our documentation for Traffic Incident API :

> developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/incident-data.html

Comment: No part of this answers the question.